# How do I get ahold of my cell when clicking in collectionView using rx?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, rx-swift

In my old project I did a small animation when clicking a `cell`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.15, y: 1.15)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        cell?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: nil)
        if self.fbHasLoaded == true {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "collectionViewToCookieRecipe", sender: indexPath.row)
        }
    }
```

Now I'm trying to refactor my project using `rx swift`, but I'm not sure how to get ahold of the `cell` when clicking one in the `collectionView`. I have managed to get a hold of the `model` and the `cell` like this:

```
Observable.zip(myCollectionView.rx.itemSelected, myCollectionView.rx.modelSelected(RecipesCollectionViewCellViewModel.self))
    .bind { indexPath, model in
        print(model)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But how do I get ahold of the `cell` so that I can do my animation stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using whichever variable you assigned to your collection view, I normally access it using something like this in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
myCollectionView.rx.itemSelected
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] indexPath in
        let cell = self?.myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        // Perform your animation operations here
    }).diposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Based on your example, you can use the same idea and access your cell using the `cellForItem(at:)` function:

```
Observable.zip(myCollectionView.rx.itemSelected, myCollectionView.rx.modelSelected(RecipesCollectionViewCellViewModel.self))
    .bind { indexPath, model in
        let cell = self?.myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? MyCollectionViewCell
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Ah, that's really neat. Thanks a lot for clearing that up! @Jeriel Ng